# Como pasar de jquery a js puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy tratando de agregar una clase a un label cada vez que presiono una tecla en un input, encontre este codigo, pero no logro pasarlo a js puro. Me ayudan???

```
$(".contenedor-formularios").find("input, textarea").on("keyup blur focus", function(e) {

        var $this = $(this),
            label = $this.prev("label");

        if (e.type === "keyup") {
            if ($this.val() === "") {
                label.removeClass("active highlight");
            } else {
                label.addClass("active highlight");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pase tu código a JS puro, deberías validar un poco como obtener el id, luego no es tan diferente la logica.

[Agregar Clase](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)
[Remover Clase](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp)

```js
document.getElementById('prueba').onkeyup = function (e) {
    var value = document.getElementById('prueba').value;
    if (value.length <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("p2").classList.remove("mystyle");
    }else{
    document.getElementById("p2").classList.add("mystyle");
    }
};
```

```css
.mystyle{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input id='prueba'>
<p id="p2">Prueba!</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Felipe,lo adapte y funciono!!!